# What is the best practice to check if the cells in an HTML table are empty?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I have a registration table in my website that has fields that need to be filled before submission. As far as I know, I have two options to make sure of that. First one is to use the 'required' attribute for each input or to check them at PHP level and using js. Which one is the better practice? Is there a better way to do it? And why?

Here is the way that I do it using HTML:

```
<form role="form" action="registration.php" method="post" id="login-form" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">username*</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Desired Username" required>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email*</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="somebody@example.com" required>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password*</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="key" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" value="Register">
</form>
```

In the PHP/JS version the code should look like this:

```
if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password)){    
     echo "<script>alert('Fields cannot be empty')</script>";    
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Use both. I highly recommend you not trusting only client-side validation.

Comment: `empty()` won't detect whitespace.

Comment: Both. Always both. Client checking to avoid to send datas and refresh a page and server checking because clients can be modified and the checking removed

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions is to have both, client & server side validation. That way you reduce server load & it's good if you later turn it into the API for eg. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

*Client-side* validation is the faster way to deal with the validation process than on the *server-side* because all the tasks happens on the webpage there itself and the network time form client to server is saved.

But in only doing *client-side* validation there is a risk of attacks clients which can easily bypass the *client-side* so here it is need to validate the strings submitted by the cilent on the *server-side* which will save your data from the dangerous inputs.

**Note :** In short, in terms of faster validation client-side is better and in terms of the security of the data server-side is a better option.

Comment: server side checkings are mandatory, since client can be modified

Comment: Yes but if you just want to check whether it is empty or not clients-side is the best practice

Comment: You want to check it on the server too.

Comment: @Cid True but think if we use both as you say the client-side checks the validation first rather moving on to the server side and that time is been saved here.

Comment: Trusting client side is a bad practice.

Comment: Yeah that's true cant't agree more:)

Comment: Checking both client and server side doesn't stop someone to prevent the client to send datas in case of errors

Comment: Yes that is true

Answer (score 0):

The truth is the server is always out a limitation on every website so as all we can we have to reduce the computing and programs from server to Client-side and to lend the render to user's computer. so if you can use js to do that never interfere PHP on this. just use js and if your problem is going to handle with pure CSS too is going to be very better.